# MySQL query execution rate

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a live chat, which involves long-polling to receive messages asap. However, since afaik web sockets are not supported cross-platform, and i couldnt find a true long polling chat example, i made a similar thing, which i am actually not sure in.

What i do is i call the script in background, which executes query each 200ms until new message appears. And this is the thing im curious about - do i execute it too often? Lets say i have around 100 ppl using this chat so it will be like 500 queries per second. How will this affect the server perfomance? Posting code im using below:

```
while (($x < 99) && ($allowloop))
{
  $query = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM messages');
  if (mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0)
  {
    usleep(200000);
    $x = $x + 1;
  } else {
    $allowloop = false;
  }
}

#processing results
```

Any tips and suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not want to do this, for the reasons you already know.

What you need is some change, a client's browser can detect, that signals a new message is present. This could be the presence of a file (with the new message?), or a string in a file.

So what you could do is:

1. A new message is available on the server.
2. The server sets the flag, either a file, or a string in a file.
3. The client browser polls the small file, checking for the flag.
4. If the flag is detect, the new message is shown.

Polling once every few seconds is more than fast enough for chatting. This method means that the clients browser doesn't invoke a MySQL query every time a check is done.

In all other cases I would use something like: http://nodejs.org

Comment: As for 2nd point, i need to have some kind of event on my server that will put a flag into a file. And this gives me next problems: 1. File per user? Is it really good? 2. Server event also must constantly check if hew message appears to put a flag into the file. But, as for my chat, 1-2 seconds delay is not good, this is why i try to show latest messages asap

Comment: Sorry, no, the server knows, of course, when it has a new message. This is when a client sends a new message. You cannot have polling, many users, and a very quick response rate. It's silly. Just remember how long it takes to make a message, and the receiver is not to know it's 1 second late. Or are your messages time critical? Some kind of game?

Comment: You could look into having an open connection, where you can transmit messages almost instantaneous. http://socket.io/get-started/chat (again with node-js, sorry) Or use HTML 5: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm

Comment: alright, websockets. is my info correct that it is not cross-platform? So if i use websockets, application will not work on some os like ios, android or wp?

Comment: Most devices try to support HTML5, but there will always be older browsers out there that don't. You can test the devices you're interested in: https://www.websocket.org/echo.html